# what does "low address bits are meaningless" mean?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to restrict access from Internet to a login page on my blog, and only make it available from my intranet.

Thus, i have defined the following location

```
location ~/ghost/signing {
    allow 192.168.0.1/24;
    deny all;
}
```

When I restart Nginx I get the following warning:
low address bits of `192.168.0.1/24` are meaningless in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site`

Also, i cannot access the location from my intranet.

So, i guess that the allow statement isn't "loaded" and that I end up denying all access to the `/ghost/signin` page.

Why are the low address bits meaningless, and how should I phrase the statement to get it to work as I intend?

I've tried to google low address bits are meaningless, but I only end up with posts in what I presume is Russian, and I don't know how to translate from Russian.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no such network as `192.168.0.1/24`, because it doesn't start on a legitimate boundary between `/24` network ranges. The last bit of the address is set, but is meaningless in this context. The correct address would be `192.168.0.0/24`, which means the range from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.0.255`.